# Accessing `self` from nested function in the field of R6 class

Tags: r, r6

I have a reproducible example below. In this example, I try to access the field `name` from the method `method()` via `self$`:

```
library(R6)

Person <- R6Class("Person",
    public = list(
        name = NULL,
        level1 = list(
            level2 = list(
                level3 = list(
                    method = function() {
                        print(self$name)
                    }
                )
            )
        ),
        initialize = function(name) {
            self$name = name
        }
    )
)

jay = Person$new(name = "Jay")
jay$level1$level2$level3$method()
```

I have several nested fields, and at some point, I have a function that accesses the public field via `self$`. However, it throws an error `Error in print(self$name) : object 'self' not found`. I found a similar issue [here](https://github.com/r-lib/R6/issues/234), however, the workaround relies on updating R6. Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 1):

In R6, methods are manipulated so that their environments can see `self`.  This is done when an instance of the class is created:  the code in `new()` modifies the environments of the methods.  However, in your example, `method()` is created and called as an element of a list, not as a function declared within `public`, so `new()` doesn't see it as a method.

To fix this, you should declare `method()` at the top level, either public or private, and get it from there during initialization.  For example,

```r
library(R6)

Person <- R6Class("Person",
                  public = list(
                    name = NULL,
                    
                    level1 = list(
                      level2 = list(
                        level3 = list()
                      )
                    ),
                    
                    initialize = function(name) {
                      self$name = name
                      self$level1$level2$level3$method <- 
                        private$themethod
                    }
                  ),
                  
                private = list(
                  themethod = function() {
                    print(self$name)
                  }
                )
)

jay = Person$new(name = "Jay")
jay$level1$level2$level3$method()
#> [1] "Jay"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: A slightly different workaround is given at https://github.com/r-lib/R6/issues/234 .